# Procedural generated 2D environment

Tags: python, 2d, auto-generate, terrain

[screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sd1Pi.jpg)
[screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SB7aH.jpg)

This game has a 2D terrain viewed from a side on perspective. Every time you start a new round, the terrain is different, in a way that it has smooth curves/peaks, but still stays within bounds. Does anyone have an algorithm for the way these terrains/lines are generated?

This is the game link:
https://www.mathsisfun.com/games/tanks.html

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Plugin on the linked webside does not work for me, and probably for a few other users. Consider including a screenshot to make you question clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Might be that what you want to do is an example of [interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation), finding a curve that goes through a set of given points.

The points could then be randomly selected within your screen area, for example marking acceptable local maximum/minimum points, and a curve of desired smoothness going through these calculated. There are algorithms for all kinds of different curves, but probable simple [polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation) would be enough for this.